# More HtAccess Rewrite Rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, seo

Greetings all,

I need help combining some htaccess rewrites, these crazy regular expressions screw with my head.

So I have a folder structure something like this:

```
     /www/mysite.com/page/member/friends.php
     /www/mysite.com/page/video/videos.php
     /www/mysite.com/page/messages/inbox.php
```

The URLs get rewritten to this:

```
     mysite.com/member/friends.php
     mysite.com/video/videos.php
     mysite.com/messages/inbox.php
```

(Notice the /page/ folder is hidden in the url, but I keep it on the server for better file organization)

The rewrite rules look something like this: (I'm new so correct me if they are flawed)

```
     RewriteRule ^video/(.*)$ /page/video/$1 [NC]
     RewriteRule ^member/(.*)$ /page/member/$1 [NC]
     RewriteRule ^messages/(.*)$ /page/messages/$1 [NC]
```

Now, I also need to do a completely different rewrite to a file called lobby.php inside of the member folder:

After the original rewrites, a sample url looks like:

```
     mysite.com/member/lobby.php?member=pws5068
```

I need a new rewrite to make it look like this:

```
     mysite.com/pws5068
```

Thank you for bearing with my super-long question here.  How can I make this happen?

**EDIT:** To make this less confusing I'm moving lobby up a directory into just /page/ by itself.

Comment: are you sure that mysite.com/member/lobby.php?member=pws5068 becomes mysite.com/pws5068 and not mysite.com/member/pws5068?

Comment: Right now it only becomes mysite.com/member/lobby.php?member=pws5068, but my goal is for it to become mysite.com/pws5068.  This is poorly organized so I apologize. I'm moving lobby up a directory to just /page/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you access 2 files in your member folder, you should differentiate them in your url structure. For instance:

```
 RewriteRule ^member/friends/(.*)$ /page/member/friends.php?id=$1 [NC]
 RewriteRule ^member/(.*)$ /page/member/lobby.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

**update**

According to your edit, it should now be

```
 RewriteRule ^member/friends/(.*)$ /page/member/friends.php?id=$1 [NC]
 RewriteRule ^member/(.*)$ /page/lobby.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Actually, I do have more files in my member folder.  I'm going to move lobby outside of it to make this less confusing because it is the unique case. So it will be /page/lobby.php and /page/member/friends.php

Comment: i corrected my answer, i had understood something incorrectly.